# Dictionary has to download again every time I log out or restart

Tags: macos, dictionary

Every time I restart my macbook or I log out of my account, I have to open the Dictionary app and download my dictionaries again to have it working (the three-fingers-tap for word definitions.)

Why is it getting deleted every time after restart and how to make the dictionaries permanent?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290669/dictionary-application-needs-to-download-dictionary-apple-dictionary-before-us?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary application needs to download dictionary "Apple Dictionary" before use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290669/dictionary-application-needs-to-download-dictionary-apple-dictionary-before-us)

Comment: Oh... It does, thanks! I actually came across that question when I was searching this stack, but I only skimmed through the first couple words and thought it didn't apply. Should have read it whole the first time, it does apply... Sorry!